# SecureSocket not available in Flash builder

Tags: air, load

Hi I'm trying to use the securesocket class that's suppose to be in as3, but when I try to import the flash.net.securesocket to my mxml it doesn't recognize it.

Does anyone know where or how I can add securesocket to my project?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/